# Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for BigQuery Python CLI

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to connect to Google BigQuery through the BigQuery API, using Python.

I'm following this page here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart

My code is as follows:

```
import os
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = './google-creds.json'

def main(project_id):
    # Grab the application's default credentials from the environment.
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    print(credentials)
    # Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
    bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

    try:
        query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
        query_data = {
            'query': (
                'SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, '
                'COUNT(*) as unique_words '
                'FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare];')
        }

        query_response = query_request.query(
            projectId=project_id,
            body=query_data).execute()

        print('Query Results:')
        for row in query_response['rows']:
            print('\t'.join(field['v'] for field in row['f']))

    except HttpError as err:
        print('Error: {}'.format(err.content))
        raise err


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('project_id', help='Your Google Cloud Project ID.')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.project_id)
```

However, when I run this code through the terminal, I get the following error:

> *oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.*

As you can see in the code, I've tried to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as per the link in the error. However, the error persists. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: All of these solutions rely on the credentials JSON file being available on the server, which is undesirable. I really wish Google/GCP would embrace environment variables.

Comment: Please don't add any more answers to this question that simple state, "set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable". This has already been stated about 20 times and there is no need to state this again

Answer (score 121, accepted):

First - Thanks for the code - this provided to be very useful.
I would also suggest adding setting the environmental variable directly in your code - as not to set it for every environment you work on.
you can use the following code:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path_to_your_.json_credential_file"
```

I found this useful when switching between different projects that require different credentials.

Comment: hi, where i put this lines  to use google api with different acounts? thanks

Comment: The "import os" is needed only once in the beginning of your code. Change the "os.environ" before every time you are switching between accounts. Change the path to the path of the account.

Comment: Thank you so much. For newbies add the code `import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path_to_your_.json_credential_file"` in your django-project settings file if you are using django.

Comment: Note that you can use this command in powershell in order to get your own credential files:
   
    gcloud auth application-default login

Answer (score 56):

I'm not sure about `BigQuery`, but i'm using `Google Data Store` for saving. If you've installed `gcloud sdk` in your mac, you can try running this command

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. I was getting 401 whenever I tried to query anything (bigquery) using the default instance (BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService())... by simply authenticating to "application-default" it started working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I have spent much time trying to figure out how to get default credentials working with service accounts when this is what I wanted.

Comment: is that documented somewhere on the specific use case of that login?

Comment: I don't remember from where I got this :( . But found the doc here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

Comment: This is the best answer for those that want to code without putting dev pc specific files into their code. For instance if you are coding for Cloud Functions - the manual json file entries are not needed. Makes for coding closer to that environment.

Comment: I've spent literally months (on my few free minutes) trying to figure this out, and this was the answer!! Thank you

Answer (score 38):

It's looking for the environment variable in your local UNIX (or other) environment, not a variable in your python script.

You'd set that by opening up your terminal or cygwin and doing one of the following:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/to/your/client_secret.json'
```

Type that into your terminal to set the variable for just this session

Open up your .bashrc file, in UNIX by typing in nano ~/.bashrc and add this line to it underneath user specific aliases if you see that header:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/full/path/to/your/client_secret.json"
```

Then reload it by typing source ~/.bashrc and confirm that it's set by trying `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. If it returns the path, you're good.

Comment: Add one thing,  the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file could be generated through https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started (highlighted as "Go to the Create Service Account Key page")

Answer (score 15):

Note: [oauth2client is deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html), instead of `GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()` you can use [google.auth.default()](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default). Install the package first with:

```
pip install google-auth
```

In your specific example, I see you know where the JSON file is located from your code. Instead of default credentials (from environment variables), you can [use a service account directly](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#bigquery-authentication-service-account-file-python) with the [google.oauth2.service_account](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html) module.

```
credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    './Peepl-cb1dac99bdc0.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

You can use this credentials file just as you are currently doing so by passing them to [googleapiclient.discovery.build](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/reference/pydoc) or if you are using the [`google-cloud-bigquery` library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries), pass the credentials to the [google.cloud.bigquery.Client](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client) constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (which is already described in a bunch of answers) there is one more way to set generated json credentials as a default service account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<path to your generated json file>
```

That will activate a default account (and set credentials according to the provided json file) without explicitly setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, and it will be still activated after re-login or reboot without modifying .bashrc.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a c# solution

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",@"C:\apikey.json");
string Pathsave = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another workaround that I don't think was mentioned here yet. The `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials` object offers the `from_service_account_info` method (see here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/google/oauth2/service_account.py).

So you can set any variable you want in your environment and read it in and pass it into the function something like this:

```
your_data = { 
"type": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR'),
"project_id": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR'),
"private_key_id": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR'),
#... and so on with all the required Google variables....
}
your_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(your_data, scopes=your_scopes)
service = discovery.build(api_name, api_version, credentials=your_credentials)
```

I basically took all the data from my google keyfile.json and stored them in the env and did the above. That way you never need to keep your keyfile.json anywhere near your code or worse, upload it somewhere public. And that's basically it. Good luck!

PS: **I forgot to mention this also**, which might help someone who is running into the same issues as I did. While the above should work fine in development, in some production environments the `\n` will not be interpreted as a new line. Instead it will remain inside the private key. Put all of the above into a try statement and if you have the error: '**no key could be detected**' then this is most likely the problem. In that case you need to replace all **\\n** with **\n** similar as to to what has been suggested by Sumit Agrawal but kind of the other way round. That's because in some environments an automatic adding of `\` will occur for a new line indication such as `\n` in order to keep them as they are if that makes any sense. So you have to basically undo this.

You can simply do the following for one of the lines above:
`"private_key": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR').replace('\\n', '\n'),`

But again try to print them to the log file / console to see how they actually look like. If you have any `\n` in the string you know you need to clean or convert them as explained. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

It's looking for the environment variable. But I was able to solve this problem on Windows platform by using Application Default Credentials.

Steps that I followed:

- Installed Google SDK
- Then execute `gcloud init` steps to specify my defaults credentials and default project which you can change as and when needed. `gcloud` executable can be loacted in the `bin` directory where you chose to install Google SDK.
- After successfully providing the credentials, you can check in at the location `C:\Users\"yourusername"\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\legacy_credentials\"youremail"`
  . You can find the credentials stored in the JSON format there.

It helped me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 3):

The link provided in the error message, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials, says to set the *environment variable* to point at the fail that contains the JSON service credentials. It looks like you set a Python variable. Try setting your terminal's environment variable to point at the correct file.

An alternate would be to explicitly use some other credentials when you aren't running in a GCE container, like `oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` and point it directly at your client secret so you don't have to indirect through an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use different credential files without setting the environmental variable, you can use the following code:

```
from oauth2client import service_account
from apiclient.discovery import build
import json

client_credentials = json.load(open("<path to .json credentials>"))

credentials_token = service_account._JWTAccessCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(client_credentials)

bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials_token)
query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
query_data = {
    'query': (
            'SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, '
            'COUNT(*) as unique_words '
            'FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare];')
    }

query_response = query_request.query(
           projectId=project_id,
           body=query_data).execute()

print('Query Results:')
for row in query_response['rows']:
    print('\t'.join(field['v'] for field in row['f']))
```

Answer (score 2):

- Export the Google credential JSON from command line:
   `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='\path\key.json'`
  I hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a client with service account credentials using `from_service_account_json()`:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/keyfile.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is case where you can not provide credential in a file set
`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='\path\key.json'`

1. As the service account is JSON and it contains double quote character, replace every double quote with `\"`
2. Wrap the complete JSON in double quote
3. Replace every `\n` with `\\n` ( on linux ) `\\\n` (on mac)

with above changes in service account if you export it as variable, then it should be recorded correctly.

try `echo %variable_name` to confirm if it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `gcloud auth application-default login` to generate the authentication token that will be generated under .config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json

Other way is to explicitly provide the service account file location in client() function or set the variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

DOC: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#python

Answer (score -1):

In your project folder just type:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='\path\key.json'
```

Answer (score -2):

On Windows, update the 'environmental variables for your account'.
You will most likely already have a variable called: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
Simply update the path to /path/to/liquid-optics-xxxxxxxx.json
(you'll most likely have that file somewhere on your machine). Then refresh your environment (cmd or whatever) to pick up the change.