# Where to put Google Cloud client/service account secret json file?

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, secret-key

So I have the following code in my project

```
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets_file, scope=flow_scope, redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
```

Which reads from a client_secret.json file in order for me to use Google Cloud API.
Here's another piece of code that sets an environment variable for Google Cloud Storage.

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.join(dir, '../config/service_account.json')
```

Normally, I would put these info in environment variables, but I don't know how to do that with json files. Where should I put these files or how should I alter them so that I can safely push my code online without revealing my credentials?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) on how to set up authentication. If you push your code, push it without the credentials file. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159967/setting-google-application-credentials-for-bigquery-python-cli) might also help

Comment: *Your environment* variables (including credentials) will not be uploaded. When someone else will download your script and run it in *his environment*, the script will look for *his environment's* variables, so he will have to provide a file containing his credentials, in a similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the file in a secret and access that secret through the Google Cloud **Secret Manager**. This is also recommended over storing your sensitive data in an environment variable. You can find more information on how to set this up here: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/