# Cannot set PATH variable for Google BigQuery in Python - unicode error

Tags: python, google-bigquery

This is my first time using BigQuery (I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10), and I found a helpful thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159967/setting-google-application-credentials-for-bigquery-python-cli) and the [BigQuery quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), BUT when I run

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS] = "PATH\TO\file_name.json"`

I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-14-ee09f24087ab>", line 1
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "C:\Users\Jack\Downloads\StackOverflow-80e374bb80fd.json"
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I followed the instructions for getting that file, named myself owner, and did not alter the .json file. Is there a way to change the encoding? I can't find anything about encoding in the docs. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your slashes or it will be read as in invalid unicode character:

```
"C:\\Users\\Jack\\Downloads\\StackOverflow-80e374bb80fd.json"
```

Comment: Of course, I didn't even think of that... Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Windows will get you every time.