# Downloading Large data from bigquery dataset and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to download data from the big query public dataset and store it locally in a `CSV` file. When I add  `LIMIT 10` at the end of the query, my code works but if not, I get an error that says:

```
Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.
```

Thank you in Advance!

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq as gbq
import tqdm

def get_data(query,project_id):
    data = gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=project_id,configuration={"allow_large_results":True})
    data.to_csv('blockchain.csv',header=True,index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = """SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` WHERE block_timestamp>='2017-09-1' and block_timestamp<'2017-10-1';"""
    project_id = "bitcoin-274091"
    get_data(query,project_id)
```

Comment: Hi! What's your question? Is it not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BigQuery allowLargeResults with pandas.io.gbq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201923/python-bigquery-allowlargeresults-with-pandas-io-gbq)

Comment: You need to save the results of the query to a table, and then export that one to GCS and download it. Or use the storage API to pull it efficiently over the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned by @Graham Polley, at first you may consider to save results of your source query to some Bigquery table and then extract data from this table to GCS. Due to the current `pandas_gbq` library [*limitations*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#features_not_supported_by_pandas-gbq), to achieve your goal I would recommend using `google-cloud-bigquery` package as the officially advised Python library managing interaction with [Bigquery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest).

In the following example, I've used [bigquery.Client.query()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.query) method to trigger a query job with `job_config` configuration and then invoke [bigquery.Client.extract_table()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.extract_table) method to fetch the data and store it in GCS bucket:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination="project_id.dataset.table")

sql = """SELECT  * FROM ..."""

query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config) 
query_job.result()  

gs_path = "gs://bucket/test.csv"
ds = client.dataset(dataset, project=project_id)
tb = ds.table(table)

extract_job = client.extract_table(tb,gs_path,location='US')
extract_job.result()
```

As the end you can delete the table consisting staging data.