# How to fragment bigquery response into 10000 in every request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I have bigquery `'SELECT visitorId , totals.visits FROM [12123333.ga_sessions_20160602]'` which return 500k rows in one request.

But I want to fragment data from 1 to 10,000 row in one request and in next request, the next 10,001 to 20,000 will be fetch and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One option** would be to write result of your query into destination table and then use [Tabledata: list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list) API to retrieve data from that table in a paged manner either using `maxResults` and `pageToken` to retrieve page by page or `maxResults` and `startIndex` to retrieve specified set of rows.

**Another option** would be to add row_number to your query (something like below)

```
SELECT visitorId , totals.visits,  
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as num
FROM [12123333.ga_sessions_20160602]
```

with still writing result into destination temp table and then retrieve data from that table using new `num` field for grouping as `num % 10000 = {group_number}` for example . Or you can use `INTEGER(num / 10000) =  {group_number}` - whatever you like more

```
SELECT visitorId , totals.visits 
FROM tempTable
WHERE num % 10000 = 0
```

next will be with

```
WHERE num % 10000 = 1
```

and so on ...

Please note: 
second option uses expensive (*execution wise  - not billing wise*) ROW_NUMBER() function which requires all data for each partition (in this case it is only one partition  - all rows) to be in the same node - so depends on number of rows it can work or not. For your specific example with just 500K rows it's going to work  - but if you extend it to table with millions and millions rows  - it might not (depends on how much data you output in each row and number of rows)

One more note:
 - in first option you pay only once when you generate result and save it into temp table. Then - it's free in a sense that Tabledata.list API is free to use as it does not use BigQuery query per se, but rather just reads directly from underlying data.
 - in second option you pay both - and when you generate temp table **and** each time you retrieve/query yet another group - because it is all BigQuery queries. Moreover each time you get data for specific group - you are charged for scanning whole temp table - so in your case it is extra 50 times

This makes (in your case) first option around 51 times cheaper than second one :o)

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you are asking for data pagination, where page size is 10 000, 
you could use the following query

```
SELECT visitorId, totals.visits,  
FROM (
   SELECT visitorId , totals.visits, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rownum 
   FROM [12123333.ga_sessions_20160602]' 
) WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

and so on

```
SELECT visitorId, totals.visits,  
FROM (
   SELECT visitorId , totals.visits, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rownum
   FROM [12123333.ga_sessions_20160602]' 
) WHERE rownum BETWEEN 10001 AND 20000
```