# Allow large results in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to download data from bigquery table which has 3 million records. I get the error

```
 "response too large to return, try will allow_large_results = true"
```

I tried with the below command:

```
  df = bq.Query('SELECT * FROM [Test.results]', allow_large_results = True).to_dataframe()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: although quite old: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287938/error-response-too-large-to-return-in-big-query) could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to retrieve result of query that is expected to be bigger than ~128MB is to issue [query insert job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) api with destination table and allow large result flag. After result is stored in that table you can retrieve it using [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) job. Of course than you can delete that [intermediate] table
Hope you can identify respective syntax in client you are using

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but for those who land here, the way to do it is:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

...

client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig(allow_large_results=True)

q = client.query("""SELECT * FROM [Test.results]""", job_config=job_config)
r = q.result()

df = r.to_dataframe()
```

From the docs [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html).

Comment: I don't think that actually works for large results - I still see the:

 `Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.` 

error message.